# Homography matrix in Opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, homography

In `LATCH_match.cpp` in `opencv_3.1.0` the homography matrix is defined and used as:

```
Mat homography;
FileStorage fs("../data/H1to3p.xml", FileStorage::READ);
...
fs.getFirstTopLevelNode() >> homography;
...
Mat col = Mat::ones(3, 1, CV_64F);
col.at<double>(0) = matched1[i].pt.x;
col.at<double>(1) = matched1[i].pt.y;
col = homography * col;
...
```

Why `H1to3p.xml` is:

```
<opencv_storage><H13 type_id="opencv-matrix"><rows>3</rows><cols>3</cols><dt>d</dt><data>
    7.6285898e-01  -2.9922929e-01   2.2567123e+02
    3.3443473e-01   1.0143901e+00  -7.6999973e+01
    3.4663091e-04  -1.4364524e-05   1.0000000e+00 </data></H13></opencv_storage>
```

With which criteria these numbers were chosen? They can be used for any other homography test for filtering keypoints (as in `LATCH_match.cpp`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that your "`LATCH_match.cpp` in `opencv_3.1.0`" is
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.1.0/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/xfeatures2D/LATCH_match.cpp

In that file, you [find](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.1.0/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/xfeatures2D/LATCH_match.cpp#L13):

```
// If you find this code useful, please add a reference to the following paper in your work:
// Gil Levi and Tal Hassner, "LATCH: Learned Arrangements of Three Patch Codes", arXiv preprint arXiv:1501.03719, 15 Jan. 2015
```

And so, looking at http://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.03719v1.pdf you will find

> For each set, we compare the first image against each of the remaining
>   five and check for correspondences. Performance is measured using the
>   code from [16, 17]<sup>1</sup> , which computes recall and 1-precision
>   using **known ground truth homographies between the images**.

I think that the image `../data/graf1.png` is https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.1.0/samples/data/graf1.png that I show here:

[image]

According to the comment [Homography matrix in Opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564541/homography-matrix-in-opencv/37565570?noredirect=1#comment62624557_37565570) by [Catree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6055233/catree)  the original dataset is at http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/affine/det_eval_files/graf.tar.gz where it is said that

> Homographies between image pairs included.

So I think that the homography stored in file `../data/H1to3p.xml` is the homography between image 1 and image 3.

Comment: So you're saying that this is an ad-hoc matrix. So how can I obtain such a matrix for a generic image?

Comment: This image comes from a well known computer vision [dataset](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/data-aff.html). The paper that firstly describes the methodology and introduces the dataset is from my knowledge: [A Performance Evaluation of Local Descriptors](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/affine/det_eval_files/mikolajczyk_pami2004.pdf). The homography relates the geometric transformation between two views for a planar surface and from a perspective projection. Thus you cannot use this homography for other images but you can estimate the homography with a robust scheme (RANSAC).

Comment: You can use [cv::findHomography](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780) with RANSAC. The planar assumption is very important, the points must lie on a plane in the 3D world (like a wall, a book, etc.). The RANSAC is used to eliminate the outliers. Basically, you pick 4 points randomly (the minimal number of points to estimate an homography) and you check if sufficient nb of points agrees with the model, otherwise you pick another 4 points. At the end, you get the homography and the inliers/outliers. The inliers must be in majority also.